# How to dynamically load python modules with same name and different path in same python process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I have two identical modules `mymod` (but with different version) in two paths `abc/` and `cde/`

```sh
abc/mymod/
 - __init__.py
 - A.py
```

```sh
cde/mymod/
 - __init__.py
 - A.py
```

where `__init__.py` contains:

```py
from . import A.py
```

I want to load both modules dynamically with `importlib` in one python instance:

```py
aMod1 = ... # import module abd/mymod
aMod2 = ... # import module cde/mymod

print(aMod1.A)
print(aMod2.A)
```

**Output:**:

```
<module 'mymod.A' from '.../abc/mymod/A.py'>
<module 'mymod.A' from '.../cde/mymod/A.py'>
```

How can that be done properly and isolated?

Note: We have troubles that the **second** `aMod2.A` also refers to `.../abc/mymod/A.py` (instead of `.../cde/mymod/A.py`)
since `python` already loaded a module with name `mymod.A`

Comment: You can't have two modules with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This would be anti-pythonic because Python holds a cache for loaded module indexed by the module name, and here you want 2 distinct modules to share the same name. Said differently I strongly urge you not to go that way.

If for any reason you have no other choice, it is possible by tweaking `sys.path` and `sys.modules`:

```
# add first folder to sys.path and import first module
sys.path.append('.../abc')
import mymod as mymod_abc

# clean up sys.path and sys.modules
sys.path.remove('.../abc')
del sys.modules['mymod.A']
del sys.modules['mymod.B']

#add second folder to sys.path and import second module
sys.path.append('.../def')
import mymod as mymod_def
```

From that point you should have both modules accessible

```
print(mymod_abc.A)
print(mymod_def.A)
```

should give:

```
<module 'mymod.A' from '.../abc/mymod/A.py'>
<module 'mymod.A' from '.../dec/mymod/A.py'>
```

But this is really an ugly hack...

Comment: But is it really not possible to load a module by another name in any directory??

Comment: @Gabriel: if names are different, there will be no problem. But module names are expected to be unique. That being said, my code demonstrate that it is possible...